# How To create correct Join between two tables?

Tags: sql, view, sql-view

I have two tables and I want to get the data from both tables.

CustomerDetails

```
Id Customer1 Customer2
1  1         2
2  2         1
3  1         3

CustomerName

Id Name
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

output should be

```
Id Customer1 Customer2
1   a         b
2   b         a
3   a         c
```

I tried with inner join but it only worked for one column and not for both.

How do i get this data from a sql query.

Please help me  find this.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried with two column in `ON` clause with `OR`. what you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **2** `join`s

```
select t1.id,t2.name customer1 ,t3.name customer2
from customerdetail t1 
join customername t2 on t1.customer1=t2.id
join customername t3 on t1.customer2=t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id,
       CN1.Name AS Name1,
       CN2.Name AS Name2
FROM   CustomerDetails CD
       JOIN CustomerName AS CN1
            ON CD.Customer1 = CN1.ID
       JOIN CustomerName AS CN2
            ON CD.Customer2 = CN2.ID
```

I would do it with `LEFT JOIN` as it would be more safe. I do not know if you do have always values for both `Customer1` and `Customer2`

Answer (score 0):

This should be work:

```
SELECT CD.Id,
   CN1.Customer1,
   CN2.Customer2
FROM   CustomerDetails CD
   JOIN CustomerName AS CN1
        ON CD.Customer1 = CN1.ID
   JOIN CustomerName AS CN2
        ON CD.Customer2 = CN2.ID
```